# Расположение блоков вокруг одного большого

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, css3

Как расположить блоки по такой схеме?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пока редко пользуюсь гридами в продакшене, но возможно в вашем случае это уместно:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
    display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

div {
  background-color: #000;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.center {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
.flex { display: flex; }

.row div {
  height: 40px;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.aside {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 2px;
}

.aside div {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 4px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.aside div:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.central {
  width: calc(50% + 4px);
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="row flex">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="aside">
    <div>5</div>
    <div>7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="central"></div>
  <div class="aside">
    <div>6</div>
    <div>8</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row flex">
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
</div>
```